# How to modify a column in a SQLite3?

Tags: python, list

I have a list A has many columns. 
The question is how to replace the value 1 in column y based on the previous value.

```
A = [ d   x    y    z
      0   1    2    5
      1   2    1    9
      2   8    1    2
      3   3    40   7
      4   6    1    7
      5   4    30   3
      6   8    40   8
      7   9    1   10
      8   6    1    4
      9  10   10    7]
 The expected answer should be :  
A = [ d   x    y    z
      0   1    2    5
      1   2    2    9
      2   8    2    2
      3   3    40   7
      4   6    40   7
      5   4    30   3
      6   8    40   8
      7   9    40   10
      8   6    40   4
      9  10    10   7]
```

Many thanks in advance...

Here is my code, and I am trying to modify column y and save it in the same table1.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import numpy
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
conn.text_factory = str 
cur = conn.cursor()
A = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")


with open('output_data1001.csv', 'w') as f: 
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['d', 'x','y','z'])
  writer.writerows(A)
```

Comment: can you show us the so called list A in a format that would actually run in python? A list does not really have "columns". What datatype is A? is it a dataframe? is it a list containing lists?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the format that your list is in.  Python doesn't read lists this way.  There are a couple of ways to do this but they all require either thinking about your list in a different way or formatting this as something other than a list.  If you want to keep it as a list, you can make it a list of lists:

```
A = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 10], 
    [2, 1, 1, 40, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10], 
    [5, 9, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 7]]
```

Now, you can reference sub-lists by their index, and make any changes you want:

```
for i in range(len(A[2])):
    if A[2][i]==1:
        A[2][i]=A[2][i-1]

print(A[2])
>>>[2, 2, 2, 40, 40, 30, 40, 40, 40, 10]
```

You could also call the list an array, rather than a list:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                [1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 10], 
                [2, 1, 1, 40, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10], 
                [5, 9, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 7]])

for i in range(0,len(A[2])):
    if A[2, i]==1:
        A[2, i]=A[2, i-1]

print(A[2])
>>>[2, 2, 2, 40, 40, 30, 40, 40, 40, 10]
```

Or it could be a dictionary:

```
A = {"d":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    "x":[1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 10], 
    "y":[2, 1, 1, 40, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10], 
    "z":[5, 9, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 7]}

for i in range(len(A["y"])):
    if A["y"][i]==1:
        A["y"][i]=A["y"][i-1]

print(A["y"])
>>>[2, 2, 2, 40, 40, 30, 40, 40, 40, 10]
```

Python is a little looser with data structures than other languages so it is easy to get tripped up by them in the beginning, since python will let you do alot without being fully cognizant of what data type you are using, but, in general, you should always consider your data type and the syntax conventions behind it before attempting to structure your data in that way.

Comment: Now that you’ve posted your code I can see that this isn’t a list or an array or a dictionary or any other form of native python data structure. This is a dataframe. Nixon gave you instructions on how to do this with a dataframe below.

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are not arrays. They don't have columns.  You can make lists of lists, though, which make it possible to call things like "A[2][3]".  Or in this case, just have a dictionary where the keys are "d", "x", "y", and "z", and the respective values of those are lists representing each column.

```
>>> A = {}
>>> A['d'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> A['x'] = [1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 10]
>>> A['y'] = [2, 1, 1, 30, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10]
>>> A['z'] = [5, 9, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 7]
>>> A['y']
[2, 1, 1, 30, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10]
```

Then you can just write a loop to look through all of the 'y' values from the second position onward, and replace any ones with the previous value:

```
>>> for i in range(1,len(A['y'])):
...     if A['y'][i] == 1:
...             A['y'][i] = A['y'][i-1]
...
>>> A['y']
[2, 2, 2, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 10]
```

EDIT: I see from your more recent edits that this isn't a list at all that you're working with, but what's known as a data frame from the Pandas module. Again, "lists" and "arrays" mean very specific forms in Python.  But the same logic can work:

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {'d': pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
          'x': pd.Series([1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 10]),
          'y': pd.Series([2, 1, 1, 30, 1, 30, 40, 1, 1, 10]),
          'z': pd.Series([5, 9, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 7])}
A = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

for row in range(A.shape[0]):
    if A['y'][row] == 1:
        A['y'][row] = A['y'][row-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but the solutions are not working!!  my code is above, How to modify column y as I did explain it above!

Comment: As people have remarked, you're not using a list; you're using a Pandas dataframe.  See my edit.